# BinaryFormatter in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, binaryformatter

I am building a WCF RIA service used for Silverlight application.
I am using BinaryFormatter.Serialize() to serialize my data to binary array before sending back to client side (silver light).

However, Silverlight 4 doesn't support BinaryFormatter yet, could you advise how to deserialize a byte array back to object at client side as BinaryFormatter.Deserialize() does at service side.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some links that might help you:

- Check this project out: http://whydoidoit.com/silverlight-serializer/
- [Silverlight 3.0 Binary Serialization Support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289910/silverlight-3-0-binary-serialization-support)
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/bin_ser_in_silverlight.aspx

  - "In Silverlight, there is no choice if you want to use binary serialization. As there is no BinaryFormatter in Silverlight, the only solution is sharpSerializer."